# initializing a field in an interface

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to initialize a `patientId` in an interface with the value `id`from another component

My Interface

```
export class Labtest {
 
    patientId!:string   
}
```

PatientDetailsComponent

```
export class PatientDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  ...
  ngOnInit(): void {
  const id=this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
   console.log(id);
}
}
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize an interface. Interfaces do not have default values either. You can extend a base class that has the default values you want instead.